# why I get strange value after using calloc function in c when i print each element and print the whole value?

Tags: c, calloc

I'm new to see and  just experimenting some function of it. I came across `calloc()` function.
I wonder why the whole variable printed, is not same as each of the indexes . shouldn't the variable value be `0`?

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main()
{
    int *array;
    array = calloc(100,sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n",array);
    for(int i  = 0 ; i<sizeof(array);i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    } 
    free(array);
}
```

and the output is

```bash
-1300734400
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I expected that the value printed in the `printf("%d\n",array);` would be zero

Comment: `sizeof(array)` is the size of the ***variable*** `array`, i.e. the size of a pointer. It's not the number of elements of the array. Furthermore, `sizeof` returns the size in *bytes*.

Comment: Also note that the proper `printf` format to print pointers is `%p`. And you need to cast the pointers to `void *`.

Comment: Oh, and `printf("%d\n",array)` prints the pointer (with the wrong format as I mentioned above), not any value inside the memory you have allocated.

Comment: I think learning C by experimenting is a difficult way to learn C: often "experiments" will have undefined behavior which means the results will be difficult to interpret. In my opinion you're much better learning C using a good reference or tutorial (with a modern compiler with every possible warning turned on, use of sanitizers and so on).

Comment: @PaulHankin
can you recommend a proper course?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `printf("%d\n",array);` This is wrong, you are printing the address of the array, not the contents. In case you mean to actually print the address, you should use `%p` and also cast the pointer to `(void*)`.
- `i<sizeof(array)` This is wrong.

  - For a normal array, `sizeof` gives the size in bytes but `array[i]` assumes `int` item number `i`, not a byte. To get the number of items of an array, you must do `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)`.
  - *However* you don't actually have an array here but a pointer to the first element. So you can't use `sizeof` at all or you will get the size of the pointer! Typically 2 to 8 bytes depending on system.
- `#include "stdio.h"` When including standard library headers, you should use `<stdio.h>`. The `" "` syntax is for user-defined headers.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
printf("%d\n",array);
```

Since `array` has type `int *`, you're attempting to print the value of of the pointer, not what it points to.  Also, the `%d` format specifier is for printing an `int` value, not a `int *` value.  You should instead use `%p` to print the pointer.